# ffmpeg input rtsp error

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, video-streaming, ip-camera

I played url *rtsp://admin:admin@camera-ip:4455* successfully this link from camera.
but when i get it by ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:admin@camera-ip:4455 -codec copy -f rtmp:/streaming-ip:1935/RTMP/test
```

i got error :

```
[rtsp @ 0x241f0e0] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP
[rtsp @ 0x241f0e0] method PAUSE failed: 455 Method Not Valid in This State
[rtsp @ 0x241f0e0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:admin@camera-ip:4446':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session/2.0
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://streaming-ip:1935/RTMP/test':
  Metadata:
    title           : RTSP Session/2.0
    encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_alaw ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), 8000 Hz, mono, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[rtsp @ 0x241f0e0] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP
rtsp://admin:admin@camera-ip:4446: Operation not permitted
[flv @ 0x250ca00] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x250ca00] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

what is the reason? and what can i do to solve this problem.

Thank for help.

Comment: Add `-analyzeduration 20M -probesize 20M` before `-i` and see.

Comment: Thanks for help but it's not working. i think the reason is rtsp://admin:admin@camera-ip:4446: Operation not permitted but i don't know why. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to convert RTSP stream to RTMP. To divide your problem in to pieces, I would suggest to make sure that you are able to receive RTSP stream successfully, once you verify that you can try to convert it to RTMP.

Using ffplay, you can verify if ffmpeg can receive RTSP stream properly. You can use Wireshark to capture the RTSP communication as well.

RTMP used 1935 port, make sure you have a permission to open TCP socket on that port. Use sudo in case. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try forcing the TCP protocol:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:admin@camera-ip:4455 -codec copy -f rtmp:/streaming-ip:1935/RTMP/test
```